# How to Async httpclient with Patch Method

Tags: c#, azure-devops

I am trying to consume [this API] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/release/approvals/update). Below is my code, but i am getting 400 bad request.

```
HttpContent z = new StringContent("{\"status\": \"approved\",\"comments\": \"" + Request.QueryString["comment"].ToString() + "\"}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");                    

public static async  Task PatchAsync(Uri requestUri, HttpContent content)
{
    try
    {                 
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var method = new HttpMethod("PATCH");
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, requestUri)
            {
                Content = content
            };

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                Convert.ToBase64String(
                    System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                        string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", "XXXXXXXXX"))));

            //using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(requestUri, content))
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request))
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                respApproval = responseBody;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        respApproval = ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `requestUri`?

Comment: Can you see in fiddler that the body of your request (content) is a appropriate json string.

Comment: @levininja requestUri would be  'System.Uri uri = new System.Uri(rmdomain + "projectname" + "/_apis/release/approvals/" + "releaseid" + "?api-version=4.1-preview.3")'

Comment: Where you have "releaseid" you need to have a variable for the approvalId.  Maybe you just need to remove the quotes (if releaseid is the name of a variable that has your approvalId).

Comment: I just fixed that and was about to reply and saw your comment @levininja. That was the issue i was passing releaseid instead of approvalid. Marina Liu's note had me thinking on incorrect parameters. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you only provide part of the code, I posted my code (which can update approvals successfully) below for your refernce:

```
public static async void ApproveRelease()
{
  try
  {
    var username = "alternate auth or PAT";
    var password = "password";
    string accountName = "https://account.visualstudio.com";
    string projectName = "projectname";
    int approvalid = id;
    var approveReleaseUri = "https://accountname.vsrm.visualstudio.com/projectname/_apis/release/approvals/approvlID?api-version=4.1-preview.3";

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
        Convert.ToBase64String(
          System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
            string.Format("{0}:{1}", username, password))));

        var method = new HttpMethod("PATCH");
        string approvveReleaseMetaData = "{\"status\":\"approved\", \"comments\":\"Good to go\"}";
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, string.Format(approveReleaseUri, accountName, projectName, approvalid, apiVersion))
        {
            Content = new StringContent(approvveReleaseMetaData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
        };

        using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result)
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
  }

}
```

By referring the blog [Using ReleaseManagement REST API’s](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chandananjani/2016/04/15/using-releasemanagement-rest-apis/).

**Note:** you can only update a release approval which status is `pending`. If you try to update a release approval which approval status is `approved` or `rejected`, you will also get the `400 bad request` response.

Comment: Thanks for the "Using ReleaseManagement REST API’s." link that was really helpful.