# Why is there no out of the box support for PATCH in HttpClient?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm using the built-in `Httpclient` to call an endpoint using a PATCH request.

Implementing our own extension method to do this is trivial and that question has been asked many times.

Why hasn't framework team added a `PatchAsync` method on the `HttpClient` or even a `Patch` property on `HttpMethod`?

My concern is that Patch is a very common use case nowadays and if they haven't included it, there might be something I'm missing and I really shouldn't do it?

Apologies for the simplicity of the question but I'm torn between requesting the API team to change the PATCH endpoint into a PUT to just use built-in functionality rather than creating an extension method for this.

My question is not about how to implement this, it's just why its not built in and if there might be any caveats on me implementing the extension and use PATCH rather than anything else provided built-in in the framework.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Async httpclient with Patch Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49904854/how-to-async-httpclient-with-patch-method)

Comment: @mjwills implementing an extension method, a wrapper or something like that is relatively trivial and is not the question. The question is why something as basic and as widely used as a PATCH was left out from the HttpClient or even just the HttpMethod class and if this was simply because they didnt consider it at the time or if there are any other caveats and we should really not use it.

Comment: The answer is exactly what you said - `implementing an extension method, a wrapper or something like that is relatively trivial`. This is a feature that is not commonly used. But, if you need it **you can write it trivially yourself**. As such, this feels like Microsoft made the right trade-off - keep the surface area small (for the majority of scenarios), with the ability to add your own extension method if you need the extra functionality itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the set of HTTP methods is [open ended](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.1), they don't necessarily provide a specific .NET method for every HTTP Method - e.g. there's no `OptionsAsync` either. For any method without a dedicated specific method, that's what [`SendAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.sendasync?view=netframework-4.7.2) is for<sup>1</sup>.

You can always write an extension method called `PatchAsync` that wraps the `SendAsync` call if `PATCH` is a common use case for you.

---

<sup>1</sup>As well as allowing you to specify options not otherwise available to you via the overloads of the dedicated methods when you are using an HTTP method with a provided .NET Method.

Comment: Thanks for the response Damien although it's not exactly what I'm looking for. I understand having an overload for each verb is definitely not a good practice and would be more than happy to use SendAsync. The issue with this is that HttpMethod doesn't even have a Patch Property, so we'd have to hardcode the "PATCH" string somewhere in our code and build the HttpMethod using the constructor rather than the convenience of the properties. HttpMethod has properties for OPTIONS and even TRACE so I wonder why something as basic as PATCH was left out and if there any potential caveats of me using it

Comment: @Pablo - even in RFC 7231 which I linked to, there are only 8 methods given there and `PATCH` isn't among them. `HttpMethod` seems to have just those methods (minus `CONNECT`) as built ins, but you can pass any string to it's constructor. Basically, it's an open ended system and `SendAsync` is the "escape hatch" if the common functionality doesn't meet your use case.

Comment: Damien, it might be, like you say, that only those 8 methods are considered the "default standard" and that's why they are the only ones implemented for simplicity, even though PATCH is defined on a different RFC (5789). The main thing I was after was if maybe the framework team saw some potential caveats when using PATCH that myself as a layman developer am not seeing but this doesn't seem to be the case and it's just a framework design decision. Thanks for pointing me into the RFC, it definitely helps making me feel at ease :D